# Kotlin, MVVM. Few events inside click listener fo RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-databinding

i'm trying to create app using Kotlin and MVVM architecture.

I'm working with RecyclerView and attach click listener like Google recommends

```
class ProductsFragment : Fragment() {
  ...

  override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    ...

    viewModelAdapter = myAdapter(myClickListener {
      //Doing what i need with clicked item

    })

    ...

  }

  ...
}

class myClickListener(val listener: (ListItem) -> Unit) {
    fun onClick(listItem: ListItem) = listener(listItem)
}
```

In this simple example click listener works fine. But when i try to change myClickListener class, like:

```
class myClickListener(val listener: (ListItem, String) -> Unit) {
    fun onClick(listItem: ListItem, action: String) = listener(listItem, action)
}
```

i have compilation errors here

```
viewModelAdapter = myAdapter(myClickListener {
  //Doing what i need with clicked item
})
```

Can someone please explain how to correctly pass changed myClickListener to Adapter after my changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can omit names only if you have single param. Kotlin will offer this single param as `it`. If you need more than one param, you have to be explicit. Try this code:

```
viewModelAdapter = myAdapter(myClickListener { first, second ->
  //Doing what i need with clicked item
})
```